# window.history.back not working on new window with Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser-history

I have a page with a link that opens a new window with a div and an iframe. The user can navigate through the web that it's inside the iframe and the div shows information.

The user wants an option to go back on pages that he visited inside the iframe, so I put an image on the div to allow that option. The image has the `onClick` event that calls `history.back()` method.

The problem that I have it's that in Firefox when I try to go a page back, the iframe stills showing the page that I'm seeing but if I try in Chrome it works great, I can visit all the sections that has my page and I can go back clicking on that image.

I tried to use the browser's context menu but in Firefox does nothing.

Comment: What do you mean? `history.back()` does not work or the iframe does not go back ?

Comment: I edited my question, maybe I explained it bad. The iframe does not go back on Firefox, but in Chrome it goes back.